# Flutter: access notification settings from Android Intent

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to access notification settings from AndroidIntent but i am not able to find the correct service name.

I have tried almost all the services where we had something related to the notification.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings

Here is the code incase someone might ask.

```
final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                      action: 'android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS');
                  intent.launch();
                  //Aandroid.settings.NOTIFICATION_ASSISTANT_SETTINGS 
                  //android.settings.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS
                  //android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS
                  //ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS nnn
                  //EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE
                  //ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS                 
                },
```

I am adding the picture of notification settings which i want to open by android intent (Flutter).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a long search, I found the solution that will show the intended notification settings.

**This is only for Flutter.**

I found an [app_settings plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings). Just add it in pubspec.yaml and install it.

After that just one line of code.

```
RaisedButton(

                onPressed: () {
                  // AppSettings.openLocationSettings();
                  AppSettings.openNotificationSettings();
                  //  openWIFISettings();
                },
)
```

There are multiple settings too which you can use. I have tested some of them. Like above I have tested 3 settings.

```
Notification
Location
Wifi
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution from [halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334841/13498522)

```
RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
    // AppSettings.openLocationSettings();
    AppSettings.openAppSettings(type: AppSettingsType.notification);
    //  openWIFISettings();
},)
```

Don't forget add [app_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official API to open notifications settings directly.
Instead what you can do is to open the settings via intent `Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` this will not open the notification settings but it may help take user a step closer to the notification settings.